# Help proving no positive integer solutions exist

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

I have been having a lot of problems proving that there are no positive integer solutions $(a,b)$ such that $a^3b+2$  and  $b^3a+2$ are both perfect squares. I've been able to show that $a^3b+2$ and $b^3a+2$ must both have the same parity and must both be odd. But I'm having trouble finding a contradiction that allows me to say there are no solutions. I've looked at them both $\mod(4)$ and $\mod(8)$ but haven't gotten anything helpful. Would anyone be able to help me?